# Проблема с формой, google script и таблицами

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть готовая форма на html + css (и чуть-чуть js), и мне необходимо чтобы она собирала данные, которые заполнил пользователь, и отправляла на нашу почту с личной почты пользователя (это ключевой момент, который не позволяет использовать гугл форму), а также направляла данные в гугл таблицу по параметрам из формы."
У меня поджимают сроки, поэтому совсем не успеваю освоить объекты и методы google script. Поэтому прошу о помощи. Может есть у кого готовый шаблоны, который я могу подключить к форме? 
Код формы: https://pastebin.com/AVzhmefG
Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Олег, здравствуйте. Мы здесь по-русски пишем. Пожалуйста, переведите вопрос.

Comment: А, я думал stackoverflow только англоязычная платформа. Сейчас отредактирую.

Comment: Есть [so], а есть StackOverflow на русском (и ещё на португальском и японском). Сайты в одной системе, но разные. На русскоязычном другие участники и список допустимых тем пошире.

Comment: Тем не менее, правила сайта не шибко зависят от языка, и вам стоит подготовить [mcve] с описанием возникшей проблемы.

Comment: В код не глядел - слишком много его. Но браузеры поддерживают схему mailto, её можно использовать в аттрибуте action у формы.

Answer (score 0):

Все будет зависеть от выбранной технологии.

### Хостинг статических файлов

Положим, что вы хостите форму на какой-то сервере. Тогда, вам необходимо реализовать следующие возможности:

- аутентификация пользователя на стороне клиента
- вызов Google API, типа такого https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

Выходит, что Google Apps Script вам тут понадобится только как Execution API, чтобы вызвать какие-то дополнительные опции. Например, туже отправку писем.

### Google Apps Script web app

Все тоже самое, кроме аутентификации. Этот воркфло будет пройден для домена script.google.com автоматически и вам не нужен будет хостинг. Публикация должна быть от имени пользователя, запускать может кто угодно.

### Веб-сервеер

Оба предыдущих метода не дают возможности оперировать даными на стороне сервера. Идеальным случаем будет запуск сервера с формой, который обрабатывает события после отправки формы. Например, создает записи в базе данных или Таблице Google.